# Bash env var existence check refactor

Tags: string, bash, environment-variables

I need to check if a list of env vars are existing. 
Now I'm doing this which of course is a very dumb solution:

```
if [ -z "$MONGOLAB" ]; then
  echo "Missing \$MONGOLAB"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$APP_PORT" ]; then
  echo "Missing \$APP_PORT"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$ENV" ]; then
  echo "Missing \$ENV"
  exit 1
fi
... more checks here
```

How could I refactor this? :)

Comment: Do you need to distinguish between a variable being unset and a variable having a null value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop and check all of them there:

```
for var in MONGOLAB APP_PORT ENV; do
    [[ -z "${!var}" ]] && echo "Missing \$$var"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is:

`[[ $MONGOLAB && $APP_PORT && $ENV ]] || exit 1`

If you happen to run a long sanity check with multiple variables, and the code becomes ugly, I suggest to use **@anubhava**'s solution, which is far more elegant.

I usually use a *die* function instead of `exit 1` to be more descriptive to the user in terms of human readable description and exit status code:

```
##
# die (optional status version): Print a message to
# stderr and exit with either the given status or
# that of the most recent command.
# Usage: some_command || die [status code] "message" ["arguments"...]
#
die() {
  local st="$?"
  if [[ "$1" != *[^0-9]* ]]; then
    st="$1"
    shift
  fi
  warn "$@"
  exit "$st"
}
```

This function is taken from [Common utility functions (warn, die)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/101) which I encourage you to read further, and maybe use a different version which suites your needs best.
Notice that `die` uses a function named `warn` which you can find in the same link above.

**P.S.**

Please note that by convention, environment variables (`PATH`, `EDITOR`, `SHELL`, ...) and internal shell variables (`BASH_VERSION`, `RANDOM`, ...) are fully capitalized. All other variable names should be lowercase. Since 
                variable names are case-sensitive, this convention avoids accidentally overriding environmental and internal variables.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

err=
for v in MONGOLAB APP_PORT ENV; do
    err="$err${!v-$v not set$'\n'}"
done
if test -n "$err"
then printf "%s" "$err" >&2; exit 1
fi

echo "All environment variables set"
exit 0
```

It improves on your solution in that it informs the user of all the required but unset variables at once, avoiding the typical annoying back-and-forth with the script to satisfy it.

We build up the error value by adding a message to it for each unset variable, then if it's non-empty, print it and abort.

The `${!v-...}` construct is an indirection - if there's a variable named `$v`, then substitute nothing, else substitute our message.

#### Alternative version

This uses an array of the required variables, and builds a one-line error message:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

required_vars=(MONGOLAB APP_PORT ENV)
missing_vars=''
for v in "${required_vars[@]}"; do
    missing_vars="$missing_vars${!v-$v }"
done
if test -n "$missing_vars"
then printf "Unset required variables: %s\n" "$missing_vars" >&2; exit 1
fi

echo "All environment variables set"
exit 0
```

#### Alternative, as a function

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

check_vars() {
    local m=''
    for v in "$@"; do
        m="$m${!v-$v }"
    done
    if test -n "$m"
    then printf "Unset required variables: %s\n" "$m" >&2; return 1
    fi
}

check_vars MONGOLAB APP_PORT ENV

echo "All environment variables set"
exit 0
```